# Codeigniter Image and Source URL

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with Codeigniter URL. I have a controller "welcome.php" :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['tiung'] = 'index';
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }

    public function dor($bus)
    {
        $data['tiung'] = $bus;
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

and a view "welcome_message.php" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
    sesuatu <?php echo $tiung?>
    <img src="fragor.jpg" width="720" height="246" alt=""/>
    ladalah
</body>
</html>
```

If I want to access the controller function 'dor' with a parameter I used this :

```
localhost/hostname/index.php/welcome/dor/something
```

and it works, but the problem is the image isn't loaded. I tried to put the image file in the webroot folder, 'application' folder, and even in the 'views' folder. But the image still can't load. Where should I put the image file?

Comment: assets folder or css folder, then use the site_url funtion like site_url('assets/fragor.jpg');

Answer (score 5):

The best practice for this is to create an /images/ directory in your webroot (the folder with index.php) and use the `base_url()` function to get the link to the image, I.E.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/fragor.jpg'); ?>" width="720" height="246" alt=""/>
```

Don't forget to load the url helper either with the autoloader or manually before using `site_url()` or `base_url()`.

Also if you're using CodeIgniter's rewrite rules to remove the index.php from the URL (which it doesn't look like you're doing), don't forget to exclude the /images/ directory from the rewrite.

Comment: the problem is i have designed the web using dreamweaver. changing the site using "<?php echo base_url()?>" means i have to change a lot of url links in my pages. is there any other solution without changing the url links?

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter there is a specific way to indicate an image...like

```
echo img('images/gautam.gif');
```

put this in your view file and you need to create "images" folder at your root

Answer (score 0):

Though you have to add CI helper 'html' in autoload config, but this goes easy after.

```
<?php
$image_properties = array(
    'src'   => 'images/picture.jpg',
    'alt'   => 'Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time',
    'class' => 'post_images',
    'width' => '200',
    'height'=> '200',
    'title' => 'That was quite a night',
    'rel'   => 'lightbox'
);
img($image_properties);
?>
/* <img src="site.com/index.php/images/picture.jpg" alt="Me, demonstrating how to eat 4 slices of pizza at one time" class="post_images" width="200" height="200" title="That was quite a nigh`enter code here`t" rel="lightbox" />*/
```

OR JUST simple:

```
<?php
echo img('images/picture.jpg'); ?>
// gives <img src="site.com/images/picture.jpg" />
```