# Using correct server (Codeigniter) URLS locally in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm having trouble with using correct path names in local Javascript with a Codeigniter backend.

My Codeigniter file directory looks like this

```
-user_data
-application
-system
-assets
```

In my JS I define the path I want to use which is user_data like so:

```
var user_file_location = 'user_data';
```

I have a function (in my local JS) that preloads images based on a given url:

```
loader.addImage(image_url);
```

Now when I try to load an image from the directory user_data like so:

```
loader.addImage(user_file_location + 'grass.png')
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost/index.php/userdata/grass.png 404 (Not Found)
```

So, the url the function loader.addImage() is trying to get the image from is incorrect.

## My question

What is a good way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Should I build an ajax function that asks Codeigniter the base_url() and somehow use that in my JS?

Please help, I'm completely lost.

Comment: Post your `loader.addImage` code as well. Most likely the error is there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110144/codeigniter-image-and-source-url

Comment: Shouldn't it be GET http://localhost/index.php/user_data/grass.png ?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/12110144/… – cillosis 1 min ago - This does not reallt address the problem of using a root url in the javascript as opposed to the html

Comment: I want it to be  localhost/user_data/grass.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this technique for posting config parameters to my js code from the backend:

In my layout file i output the following:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "window.myNameSpace = new Object(); ";
echo "window.myNameSpace.baseUrl = '" . base_url() . "';";
echo "</script>";
```

Then i am able to access this parameter in the js code whereever i want, like this:

```
var imageUrl = window.myNameSpace.baseUrl + image.png
```

Comment: This will work. Is it standed practice to get access to servor config info in JS using your method?

Comment: I do not now if it can be considered standard practice but when I faced the same problem  this was the best solution i could come up with. Compared to using an ajax request this is both faster and much more convenient.

Comment: You should use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`, so the index page is included (when applicable).